# What can POLYCOLOR mean and is there a way to convert to RGB?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, color, rgb, arcview-3

It is not for the first time I found in the tables of some data column called **POLYCOLOR**. Is there any way to figure out what that means and is it somehow convertible to RGB values? If I get it right it should be connected to ArcView 3.0a color system.

[image]

Comment: It's probably a lookup type if it's AV3.2 vintage. In a lookup there would be a table that has POLYCOLOR,RED,GREEN,BLUE fields to save having to put individual values in each row. Packed colour (16 bit) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_color format also is possible but the values are too small for that.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Thanks, that means without lookup table I really can't do anything. Could the lookup table be part of mxd file or how that works?

Comment: If it is it would be referenced. It sounds more like a MapINFO sort of thing than AV3.2 though. Perhaps there's a TAB file that has the information in it.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson thank you again. This file was available for download on official site both as shapefile and tab file to make it more confusing, without any additional files. Anyway I ordered the CD which should contain batch of file including the MXD and probably MI workspace so that should make it clear and hopefully will come with some sort of coloring.

Comment: This may or may not be relevant but there is a polycolor.lut (lut=lookup table) mentioned at http://pubs.usgs.gov/of/2002/0491/pdf/pmtn_readme.pdf